# My opening "Hi everyone" in my question keeps disappearing

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, signatures

Whenever I write a question (on Stack Overflow at least) it removes the greeting I put in the message.

What is the reason for this?

It was just removed here as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not exactly. Mine is more a "why" and not a "should?".

Comment: Read the second answer to that post, by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: Basically it was decided that this stuff is noise that obscures the main information.  Think as if you're writing a book. Each chapter of a book doesn't start "Hi!"

Comment: A better question is why this feature hasn't evolved to do this more effectively; I still see tons of posts with greetings.

Comment: This is explained on Meta.SE at [Should "hi", "thanks", taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: +1 This question is deserving of an upvote, even though the idea of adding a salutation is deserving of a downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Which post are you talking about?

Comment: @Hogan: context was lost in the migration; there was a duplicate vote on this post that is now gone, it looks like. I was referring to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/140890).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - A BUG! Call in the lynch mob!

Comment: @Hogan: nah, just someone cleaning up for a migration, I'd say, or the comment was removed before the migration (possible if it was someone else who first voted to close as a dupe).

Comment: The post was closed as a duplicate on Meta.SE, @MartijnPieters, and thus the duplicate auto-comment was auto-removed. [When the question was migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250976/), the duplicate closure was broken, because it's cross-site, but the comment was not automatically restored. We'll have to keep an eye on this to see if it becomes problematic. I've seen one other question so far where this happened.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The consensus is that salutations in a question (or answer, for that matter) [are noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950) and should be edited out.

All they do is take screen real-estate, require reading and parsing (or parsing out) by those who read the question and are not relevant to the issue at hand.

So people edit them out.

Comment: What annoys me even more are the valedictions. "Thank in advance" _especially_.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen - people want to be polite, nothing wrong with being polite. What we do on Stack Overflow is not quite the norm...

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing an answer. I am interested in the origin of this "consensus". Where is it from?

Answer (score 10):

Not only do editors remove noise from posts, [the system automatically removes common greetings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/280467) from the posts on its own.