# Being polite while asking a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I try to be polite and courteous when asking for help thus I always try to end my questions with a "Thank you for the help!" or something similar (on the initial post) just to show some appreciation towards the users who are giving their time and energy to assist me.

What I am confused on is that this almost always gets edited out every single time. Sure it is not relevant, but it is ~7 extra words at the end of my questions and I think it is appropriate as I was raised to be polite and courteous in every and any situation.

Question: Is adding a mini-appreciation really that frowned upon after making a request?

Comment: You'll get your answer if/when someone edits your post to remove the last sentence, I suppose :P

Comment: This kind of annoys me too- I appreciate SO is all about the Q/A and not about 'making friends', but I would argue good manners tend to engender better attitudes all round.

Comment: It's noise. We don't care if you say thanks, we care that you write a high-quality question (or answer). And it's better to be consistent; if we allow a "Thanks!" then we can't reasonably disallow other formalities like "Greetings" and similar introductions; or all the noise posters from some cultures feel compelled to add. All this would add to a considerable amount of fluff that distracts from the actual questions. Also, consider that many good questions are mostly read by people who found it via google, who are not even addressed by your "thanks". Just thank people with upvotes instead.

Comment: @l4mpi Agreed, I suppose it is just a feeling I gotta shrug off.

Comment: What is "*polite and courteous*" is determined by the environment and context, not by the asker.  What is polite and courteous here are straight-forward, clear questions without social adornments or personal appeals.  "*Just the facts, 'maam*".

Comment: The consensus seems to be, "Don't say Thank You, it's rude". *cue narrator* You've just crossed over...into the Twilight Zone

Comment: @contactmatt: It might be more useful to think of it in the Internet equivalent terms of "hello" and "goodbye."  Don't say "hello;" we already know you're here.  Don't say "goodbye;" we already know you've finished writing.  Don't ask if you can ask, just ask.  "Thanks" is nice, but clean posts and upvotes are better.  Lost on many folks: you can always say "Thanks" in a comment, but people seem to insist that it go in the post.

Comment: there's a whole lot more to politeness then adding extra obligatory text to your posts.  Being responsive to feedback and understanding to other user's needs is infinity more important to politeness than obligatory text.

Comment: Related: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: I was also raised to be polite and courteous. But then I met the stackoverflow community. Since that time, I'm always carrying a gun with me. In the streets, I first shoot, then I ask, then I get a downvote.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, in this community what is valued is clear and concise post that get straight to the point, provide the necessary information, and don't contain "noise" that is not helpful in understanding the post.

One important aspect to keep in mind is that on SO you're not having a personal dialog with another user.  You're creating a repository of knowledge.  You don't see, "and thanks for taking the time to read this" in an encyclopedia article.

Comment: True true, I guess that just seems a little rude because I am quite thankful for everyone's help, especially since only one user can get the "credit" for it when many users may have offered other correct solutions. :/

Comment: @Austin Being "rude" is violating of the social conventions of a community.  In this community some of the values are being concise, straight to the point, excluding superfluous information, etc.  You are intentionally violating that convention that you have recognized by continuously including content that you know the community doesn't want to see in questions.  (To the point that you've asked over a hundred questions and you're *still* including this content that you know shouldn't be posted.)  *That* is rude to *me*.

Comment: @Servy an interesting point then comes to: what is a community if not the conventions of its largest group of members (the norm)...which here are effectively newbies / lower rep users who likely have a predilection to using niceties? (not that I disagree btw) I would tend to say it is less about convention, more about ultimate purpose (Q/A, future benefit). nb. an encyclopaedia article isnt one person asking a group of others a question it is a single point reference. There is no dialogue.

Comment: @SW4 Those users also value asking bad questions, being waited on hand and foot, having nothing expected of them as question askers, always getting a fast quality answer despite these actions, and never having any negative feedback of any kind conveyed.  Those neither are the "values" of this community nor would it be better off for us to change our values to incorporate them.

Comment: @SW4 SO is designed to *not* be a dialog.  It's designed to be a question and an answer *with everything else cut out*.  It's designed so that anyone in the world can read a question and answer and have an experience similar to looking at an encyclopedia, even if that's not how the content was created.  When you're looking at a question that someone answered 3 years ago you don't care if the person that asked it was thankful that someone else answered it.  You just want to make sure the question is your question and then see what the answer is.  That is the goal of the site.

Comment: @Servy - given the fact the freedoms of the masses are controlled by the few, my comment was more on the use of the word community when SO is more autocratic / governmental - as opposed to the issue at hand. Having dealt out more downvotes than I can count for appalling quality questions recently, I'm not against eradicating noise especially given it is absolutely rampant (we agree on the underlying point)

Comment: @SW4 I'd suggest giving [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html) a read.  Pay particular attention to "Three Things to Accept" items #2 and #3.

Comment: @MichaelT - thanks, have also read a fair few of sources quoted which are worth a read- its an interesting field for sure

Answer (score 10):

There's no issue with saying thank you, but there are better ways to do it than in the question:

- Voting on answers that were helpful
- Marking an answer that solved the problem
- Doing it in comments on posts that were helpful with some details as to why (helpful to future users)

Adding it to the question just adds what folks refer to as *noise*.

I do sometimes remove *thank you* lines from questions, but only when there are other edits that are required to the post. If removing a *thank you* was the only thing to edit, I would leave it there. If I see edits like that in the review queue, I would reject them as *Too Minor*.

Comment: I disagree with this sentiment.  Voting and marking the answer are there to indicate the quality of a post, not to thank the person that posted them for their time.  Votes are about the *content* not the *user*.  Additionally I see people upvoting bad and even flat out wrong answers to "thank the poster for taking the time to try to answer".  That is *actively harmful* to the community.

Comment: @Servy that wasn't the sentiment I was trying to get across, I have edited the post to clarify this.

Answer (score 8):

Several years ago, the community decided that **everything** that was not part of the question or answer, was superfluous. This was in the early days of Stack Overflow (2009), and the relevant discussion is now preserved on Meta Stack Exchange: [Should 'Hi', 'Thanks', taglines and salutations be removed from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)  .

The community still seems to feel that way today: see "[My opening 'Hi everyone' in my question keeps disappearing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251077/my-opening-hi-everyone-in-my-question-keeps-disappearing/251238#251238), or [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

To understand where this came from, you have to understand one of the motivations that Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood had when building Stack Overflow. One of the things they didn't like about forums was how much space was used by avatars, signature lines, and so on. A lot of stuff that was not related to the subject matter, but did distract from it. Jeff Atwood discussed this in a [blog post on Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/).

Stack Overflow decided to do away with all the unrelated material in posts; one could argue that they went to the other extreme by deciding that not even "Hello" and "Thank you" were welcome.

I agree with @Tanner that if removing a "Thank you" is the only thing that could be fixed about a post, you might as well let it stand. But if someone is going to edit a post anyway, removing salutations and thanks is appropriate.

We express our thanks using upvotes and accepts. This may feel a little weird at first, but it works well.